# Acessing fields within rule - ANtlr4

Tags: field, antlr4

I have a rule where I have a declaration returns

```
tablename
    returns [String fieldString, TableObj obj]
```

TableObj is a custom class that I declare in the same g4 file

```
class TableObj {
    public String realName;
    public String aliasName;
    public List<String> fields;
    public List<Relation> relations;

    public TableObj(){
       fields = new ArrayList<String>();
       relations = new ArrayList<Relation>();
    }
}
```

but when I have to try access a field of obj using $obj.field the generated code is:

_localCtx.field

instead of

_localCtx.obj.field

How do I do to obtain the second form instead of the first?

If it will need or it will help follows a snippet of my rule

```
tablename
returns [String fieldString, TableObj obj]
:
    (tablePrefix=ID { 
                        $obj.aliasName = $tablePrefix.text;
                        System.out.println( "Alias = " + $tablePrefix.text + " " + $obj.aliasName );
                    }
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ANTLR that you should report to the project issue tracker:
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues